# Posterior sampling without using pm.Potential in pyMC3

Tags: bayesian, posterior, pymc

I'm going through the **Price Is Right** example in [chapter 5](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter5_LossFunctions/Ch5_LossFunctions_PyMC3.ipynb) of [Probabilistic Programming & Bayesian Methods for Hackers](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers) and I have problems understanding the solution. I have tried to change the implementation of the solution in a way that I thought that should be also correct but I got results that deviate from those in the script.

The description of the example is given below:

> **Example: Optimizing for the *Showcase* on The Price is Right**
>
> Bless you if you are ever chosen as a contestant on the Price is
>   Right, for here we will show you how to optimize your final price on
>   the *Showcase*. For those who forget the rules:
>
> 1. Two contestants compete in *The Showcase*.
> 2. Each contestant is shown a unique suite of prizes.
> 3. After the viewing, the contestants are asked to bid on the price for their unique suite of prizes.
> 4. If a bid price is over the actual price, the bid's owner is disqualified from winning.
> 5. If a bid price is under the true price by less than \$250, the winner is awarded both prizes.
>
> The difficulty in the game is balancing your uncertainty in the
>   prices, keeping your bid low enough so as to not bid over, and trying
>   to bid close to the price.
>
> Suppose we have recorded the *Showcases* from previous *The Price is
>   Right* episodes and have *prior* beliefs about what distribution the
>   true price follows. For simplicity, suppose it follows a Normal:
>
> $$\rm{True Price} \sim \text{Normal}(\mu_p, \sigma_p )$$
>
> In a later chapter, we will actually use *real Price is Right Showcase
>   data* to form the historical prior, but this requires some advanced
>   PyMC3 use so we will not use it here. For now, we will assume $\mu_p = 35 000$ and $\sigma_p = 7500$.
>
> We need a model of how we should be playing the *Showcase*. For each
>   prize in the prize suite, we have an idea of what it might cost, but
>   this guess could differ significantly from the true price. (Couple
>   this with increased pressure being onstage and you can see why some
>   bids are so wildly off). Let's suppose your beliefs about the prices
>   of prizes also follow Normal distributions:
>
> $$ \text{Prize}_i \sim \text{Normal}(\mu_i, \sigma_i ),\;\; i=1,2$$
>
> This is really why Bayesian analysis is great: we can specify what we
>   think a fair price is through the $\mu_i$ parameter, and express
>   uncertainty of our guess in the $\sigma_i$ parameter.
>
> We'll assume two prizes per suite for brevity, but this can be
>   extended to any number.  The true price of the prize suite is then
>   given by $\text{Prize}_1 + \text{Prize}_2 + \epsilon$,  where
>   $\epsilon$ is some error term.
>
> We are interested in the updated $\text{True Price}$ given we have
>   observed both prizes and have belief distributions about them. We can
>   perform this using PyMC3.
>
> Lets make some values concrete. Suppose there are two prizes in the
>   observed prize suite:
>
> 1. A trip to wonderful Toronto, Canada!
> 2. A lovely new snowblower!
>
> We have some guesses about the true prices of these objects, but we
>   are also pretty uncertain about them. I can express this uncertainty
>   through the parameters of the Normals:
>
> \begin{align} & \text{snowblower} \sim \text{Normal}(3 000, 500 )\\\\ & \text{Toronto} \sim \text{Normal}(12 000, 3000 )\\\\ \end{align}
>
> For example, I believe that the true price of the trip to Toronto is
>   12 000 dollars, and that there is a 68.2% chance the price falls 1
>   standard deviation away from this, i.e. my confidence is that there is
>   a 68.2% chance the trip is in [9 000, 15 000].

In the first step we have to get samples from the posterior distribution.

**My solution**

I thought that we just have to sample values from the following distribution:
$$p(x|{\rm obs}) \propto p({\rm obs}|x) p(x)$$
where the priror $p(x)$ is given by:
$$p(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\tilde{\sigma} }\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \frac{(x-\tilde{\mu})^2}{\tilde{\sigma}^2} \right), \hspace{10.0mm} 
\tilde{\mu}=35000,  \tilde{\sigma}=7500
$$
The likelihood $p({\rm obs}| x)$ is obtained from the sum of normal distributions (snowblower $\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$ and Toronto trip $\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$):
$$ p({\rm obs}|x) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_{12} } \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \frac{(x-\mu_{12})^2}{\sigma^2_{12}} \right), \hspace{10.0mm} 
\mu_{12}=\mu_1+\mu_2,  \sigma_{12}=\sqrt{\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2 }\approx \sigma_2
$$

By "completing the square" of the sum of arguments in the exponential functions in $p(x|{\rm obs})$, one can show that the maximum of the posterior is at:
$${\rm argmax}_x \hspace{2mm} p(x|{\rm obs})= 
\frac{\mu_{12}\tilde{\sigma}^2 + \tilde{\mu}\sigma^2_{12} }{\sigma^2_{12}+\tilde{\sigma}^2 } \approx 17750 $$

With the following code I obtain a $p(x|{\rm obs})$ with a peak at the predicted location

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np

mu_1, mu_2, mu_k = 3e3, 12e3, 35e3
mu_12= mu_1 + mu_2

sd_1, sd_2, sd_k = 0.5e3, 3e3, 7.5e3
sd_12= np.sqrt(sd_1**2 + sd_2**2) # approx equal to sd_2

with pm.Model() as model:

    priror = pm.Normal("priror", mu=mu_k, sd=sd_k)
    obs = pm.Normal("obs", mu=priror, sd=sd_12, observed=np.array([mu_12]))

    ### we can exchange the positions of priror and likelihood 
    ### and get the same result
    # priror = pm.Normal("priror", mu=mu_12, sd=sd_12)
    # obs = pm.Normal("obs", mu=priror, sd=sd_k, observed=np.array([mu_k]))

    trace = pm.sample(40000)
```

The problem is that in the textbook the posterior is peaked at $x=20000$. I would be glad if I get an idea from where the difference comes from.

**Solution in the textbook**

For comparison, the code in the textbook is given below:

```
import pymc3 as pm

data_mu = [3e3, 12e3]

data_std =  [5e2, 3e3] 

mu_prior = 35e3
std_prior =  75e2
with pm.Model() as model:
    true_price = pm.Normal("true_price", mu=mu_prior, sd=std_prior)

    prize_1 = pm.Normal("first_prize", mu=data_mu[0], sd=data_std[0])
    prize_2 = pm.Normal("second_prize", mu=data_mu[1], sd=data_std[1])
    price_estimate = prize_1 + prize_2

    logp = pm.Normal.dist(mu=price_estimate, sd=(3e3)).logp(true_price)
    error = pm.Potential("error", logp)    

    trace = pm.sample(50000, step=pm.Metropolis())
    burned_trace = trace[10000:]

price_trace = burned_trace["true_price"]
```